# stop flash of content/redraw on hover in chart.js

Tags: image, canvas, chart.js

With [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) how do I stop flash of content if I am trying to add images to the canvas? Ideally, I want to stop redrawing the canvas on completion of the animation but on hover it redraws so I have to redraw/add the image (and get a flash of content).

Your suggestions appreciated …

Comment: video showing issue http://quick.as/oZ2BurGRZ

Comment: I got the same problem, do you have any solution?

Comment: Same here for  afterDatasetsDraw plugin for chart.js any luck ?